# How to do LabelEncoding or categorical value in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn

I am having dataset contains String columns . How can I encode the string based columns like the one we do in scikit-learn LabelEncoder

Comment: do you want LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoder?

Comment: I would prefere LabelEncoder but I won't reject HotEncoder if thats available in PySpark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're developing [sparkit-learn](https://github.com/lensacom/sparkit-learn) which aims to provide scikit-learn functionality and API on PySpark. You can use SparkLabelEncoder the following way:

```sh
$ pip install sparkit-learn
```

```py
>>> from splearn.preprocessing import SparkLabelEncoder
>>> from splearn import BlockRDD
>>>
>>> data = ["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"]
>>> y = BlockRDD(sc.parallelize(data))
>>>
>>> le = SparkLabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit(y)
>>> le.classes_
array(['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo'],
      dtype='|S9')
>>>
>>> test = ["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"]
>>> y_test = BlockRDD(sc.parallelize(test))
>>>
>>> le.transform(y_test).toarray()
array([2, 2, 1])
>>>
>>> test = [2, 2, 1]
>>> y_test = BlockRDD(sc.parallelize(test))
>>>
>>> le.inverse_transform(y_test).toarray()
array(['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris'],
      dtype='|S9')
```

Answer (score 24):

StringIndexer is what you need 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/ml-features.html#stringindexer

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
            [(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "c")],
            ["id", "category"]) 
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex") 
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df) 
indexed.show()
```